integrate $\exp(-|z|^2)/(z-1)$ over a circular contour of radius (a) $2$, and (b) $\infty$, both centered at the origin.
I am trying to integrate $\exp(-|z|^2)/(z-1)$ over a circular contour of radius (a) $2$, and (b) $\infty$, both centered at the origin. Here $|z|^2=\Re z^2 + \Im z^2$. Am I right in thinking $\exp(-|z|^2)$ is analytic at the origin, because it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equation regardless of the direction I approach the origin?
(a) So the integral should simply be $2\pi i \exp(-1)$.
(b) Are there any issues at $\infty$, which would prevent me from naively using the residue theorem for case (b) where the contour has radius $\infty$?

No, $\exp(-|z|^2)$ is not analytic.
Consider the contour $C$ described by $|z|=2$.  Then
$$
\int_C \frac{\exp(-|z|^2)}{z-1}\;dz =\int_C \frac{\exp(-2^2)}{z-1}\;dz
$$
The residue at $z=1$ is $e^{-4}$.  So the integral evaluates to
$e^{-4}\,2 \pi i$.
Similarly, for any $R>1$ we have
$$
\int_{|z|=R} \frac{\exp(-|z|^2)}{z-1}\;dz = e^{-4}\,2 \pi i .
$$
